# Is there a way to render HTML inside a PDF file?

Tags: html, pdf, flash

These past months I' being developing a portfolio, that consists of a swf file inside a pdf document.

However, it doesn't work on devices that don't have Flash installed, like iPads for example. So the client wants to port the Flash content to HTML 5, but AFAIK, that is not possible, PDF can't render HTML.

Do you know of any way to achieve this?.

Even pdf readers in iOS devices can't run javascript inside pdf files properly, so, dynamic forms made with LiveCycle Designer wont work either.

Comment: My best advice to you if you have to use HTML5, is to use an application that entirely supports it.  Like a web browser.  A PDF viewer is meant to port documents around.  You seem to be looking for a solution for something it wasn't really meant for.  You're jumping through hoops when a perfectly good solution already exists.

Comment: I know.. but you know, the trend is to kill Flash just because... People don't understand HTML 5 is not the solution to everything.

Comment: web browser for sure... if the client demands offline functionality, there are some useful offline tools available in HTML5 (like the Cache Manifest). I used this to present my portfolio in my last interview because I was nervous about whether or not I would have a reliable internet connection. more details can be found here: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: the reason flash works inside a pdf can be summed up in one word... Adobe. If they weren't related like that they probably wouldn't function that way.

Comment: Does it have to be a PDF file? If you have the source code of your swf file you could try converting the project into an Adobe Air application, which you can deploy for almost every mobile or desktop platform. Adobe Air will include the flash runtime in the application itself and wrap it with native application for each of your target platforms.

Comment: yms well that's something I need to consult with my client, but it seems like it, at least so far that was the idea.

@jRulle in that case, can I have only one file?, or I need to provide a zip with dozens of files, like index.html, images folder, etc?

Comment: The cache manifest route would be a full site (html, CSS, JavaScript, images, etc) but you wouldn't deploy it to devices as a package. You would deploy it to a web server then share the URL. The user can save the URL as a bookmark or on iOS add it to their home screen - if they go offline it loads the resources locally from the cache. If they have a connection it checks to see if there has been any changes and if so it updates the local cache to reflect those changes for the next offline use.

Comment: PDF viewers for devices are weaker than for the desktop. This is a simple reality we have to live with. All the things a full-blown PDF viewer should be able to deal with are too much for the device viewers…there is a reason for the installed size of Adobe Reader. One possibility you have is to see whether you can really get the functionality in PDF using the supported JavaScript (by your viewer of choice), and then require the use of that viewer for full user experience.